# Expected expression before '=' token in C

Tags: c

Though the pre processor assigns i = 3.14159265. When i compile it, gives an error saying expected an expression before '=' token what and why is that ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI = 3.14159265
int main()
{
    float i;
    i = PI;
    printf("My first Linux program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7942837/694576 http://stackoverflow.com/q/15626551/694576

Answer (score 4):

```
#define PI = 3.14159265
```

defines PI to be `= 3.14159265` literally including the equals sign. Thus `i = PI;` is the same as:

```
i = = 3.14159265;
```

which clearly won't compile. To fix it, remove the `=` from your definition of PI:

```
#define PI 3.14159265
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the '=' when you use the define keyword.  Including it will include the '=' in the definition.

```
#define PI 3.14159265
```

Comment: Actually the `#define` is perfectly legal. It just causes `PI` to expand to `= 3.14159265` rather than to the more useful `3.14159265`.